# How to Apply Storyboard as Style

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, storyboard, shapes

I want to apply a `Storyboard` to my `Rectangle` `Fill` like this:

```
<Rectangle Name="MyRectangle"
  Width="100"
  Height="100">
  <Rectangle.Fill>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="MySolidColorBrush" Color="Blue" />
  </Rectangle.Fill>
  <Rectangle.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.MouseEnter">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <ColorAnimation 
            Storyboard.TargetName="MySolidColorBrush"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
            From="Blue" To="Red" Duration="0:0:1" />  
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Rectangle.Triggers>
</Rectangle>
```

But I want to insert the `Storyboard` in a `Style`, i tried this:

```
<Style xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
   xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">

<Style.Triggers>

    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Shape.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation 
            Storyboard.TargetName="MySolidColorBrush"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
            From="Blue" To="Red" Duration="0:0:1" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>

</Style.Triggers>

<Setter Property="Shape.Fill" Value="Blue" x:Name="MySolidColorBrush"/>

</Style>
```

Using this code:

```
var rect = new Rectangle();

using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("myStyle.xaml", FileMode.Open))
   rect.Style = XamlReader.Load(stream) as Style;
```

But it does not work and throws an exception. How I have to change my Style?

Comment: Are you obliged to use XamlReader and all this stuff to make a simple style ? I'm not sure but i think the way you create a style is a little bit uncommon.

Comment: @HichemC I want to have the possibility to set the Style using an external resource, i.e. i want that a 3rd party can chose the Style, have you any alternatives?

Comment: you can use Class Library project, add ressource dictionaries there and then add the dll to your current project, so you can those resources via <RessourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> tag

Comment: @HichemC No, in this way i have a number of predefined styles, and I can not add more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this in your Storyboard

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
```

to

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color"
```

and remove

```
Storyboard.TargetName="MySolidColorBrush"
```

Comment: Your answer was helpful because i just change `Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"` with `Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color"` and remove `Storyboard.TargetName="MySolidColorBrush"` and it works. Edit your answer and i'll mark as accepted.