# Bind animations to ViewModel property

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I've got a "flip card"-style animation that works just fine. On one side, it has a button that, when clicked, triggers the animation "FlipOpen":

```
<Button Content="click me" Height="130">
<Button.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" >
        <BeginStoryboard  Storyboard="{StaticResource FlipOpen}">
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Button.Triggers>
```

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="FlipOpen">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" From="-1" To="1" Storyboard.TargetName="Back"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" From="1" To="-1" Storyboard.TargetName="Front"/>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="FlipClose">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" From="1" To="-1" Storyboard.TargetName="Back"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" From="-1" To="1" Storyboard.TargetName="Front"/>
    </Storyboard>
```

I would like to bind the animation to a boolean property on my ViewModel and I have tried to use DataTriggers:

a) define a style:

```
<Style x:Key="myStyle">
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FlipTheCard}" Value="true">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FlipOpen}"/>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FlipTheCard}" Value="false">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FlipClose}"/>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

b) apply it to both Grid-Containers that contain the front and back:

```
<Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Name="Back" Opacity="0" Style="{StaticResource myStyle}">
...
</Grid>
```

c) don't start the animation on button click, but bind a command that toggles the boolean to the button:

```
<Button Content="click me!" Command="{Binding ToggleFlipCard}" Height="130">
```

However, this results in an exception ("A storyboard-structure within a Style can not have a TargetName. Remove the TargetName").

**What am I doing wrong here? How can I bind these animations to a boolean property on my ViewModel?**

Thank you for any help!

Comment: could you also post your code for `FlipClose`?

Comment: I've added it in my post. It just flips back..

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206387/how-to-apply-storyboard-as-style

Comment: goobering, in your link it says "remove the TargetName". My storyboard animates two different Targets at the same time ("Back" and "Front"), if I remove the TargetNames, then the style would not know what to animate..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also found a solution...it's far from perfect on the animation side (as I don't use keyframes and just scale the x property of both at the same time) but it should give you the idea:

**Style:**

```
<Storyboard x:Key="FlipOpen">
    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
        To="0" />
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Key="FlipClose">
    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3"
         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
         From="0"
         To="1" />
</Storyboard>

<Style x:Key="GridStyle" TargetType="Grid">
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5" />
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="FrontGridStyle" TargetType="Grid"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource GridStyle}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FlipTheCard}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FlipOpen}" />
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FlipClose}" />
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="BackGridStyle" TargetType="Grid"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource GridStyle}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FlipTheCard}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FlipClose}" />
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FlipOpen}" />
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**Grid:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource FrontGridStyle}">
        <Border Width="100"
                Height="100"
                Background="Red" />
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Command="{Binding ToggleFlipCard}"
                Content="click me!" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid Style="{StaticResource BackGridStyle}">
        <Border Width="100"
                Height="100"
                Background="Green" />
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Command="{Binding ToggleFlipCard}"
                Content="click me!" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.. *yikes*

- reference Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll
- define Interaction-Triggers:

  ```
      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FlipToFront}" Value="true">
          <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource FlipOpen}"/>
      </ei:DataTrigger>
      <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FlipToFront}" Value="false">
          <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource FlipClose}"/>
      </ei:DataTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  ```

[credits](http://mark.mymonster.nl/2010/12/14/trigger-a-storyboard-on-viewmodel-changes)