# XAML Storyboard DependencyObject Error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard

I am encountering an error in my XAML application.

The error I am receiving is

> '[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path
>   '(0).(1)[2].(2)'.

I searched around and found out that something needs to go inside `<Image.RenderTransform>` tag in Page.XAML for RotateTransform, but I am not sure what since I am new to XAML and still learning.

App.XAML

```
<Storyboard x:Key="spin">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
                                           Storyboard.TargetName="{Binding}"
                                           RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" 
                                      Value="360"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Page.XAML

```
<Page.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{DynamicResource spin}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
</Page.Triggers>

<Image x:Name="image1" 
       Margin="0, 0, 5, 0" 
       Source="{StaticResource inProcessImage}"
       Width="18" 
       RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>

<Image x:Name="image2" 
       Margin="0, 0, 5, 0"  
       Source="{StaticResource inProcessImage}"
       Width="18"  
       RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

Code Behind

```
startAni("spin", image1.Name);
startAni("spin", image2.Name);

void startAni(string storyboardName, string objectName)
{
    Storyboard sb = FindResource(storyboardName) as Storyboard;

    foreach (var child in sb.Children)
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(child, objectName);

    sb.Begin(this); // do not forget the this keyword
}
```

Comment: Storyboard.TargetProperty + TargetName are weird here. Where did you get this from?

Comment: @jHilscher `TargerProperty` is generated by blend. Using `TargetName` to Bind the name since I will be using it on different images. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by this part:

```
<Page.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{DynamicResource spin}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
</Page.Triggers>
```

The Event Trigger doesn't load the storyboard properly (does not set `TargetName`). So you're seeing this error.

---

You could put the `startAni` call in the loaded event of the page (in code behind.)
This worked perfectly fine for me:

```
    public Page() {

        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += Page_Loaded;

    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        startAni("spin", image1.Name);
        startAni("spin", image2.Name);
    }
```

---

**A XAML only solution would look like this:**

```
<TimelineCollection x:Key="Ani">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames 

                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
                                           Storyboard.TargetName="{Binding}"
                                           RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" 
                                      Value="360"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</TimelineCollection>
```

Use a TimelineCollection instead of a storyboard, then you can set the TargetName in the Page.XAML. This does not need code behind at all.

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard TargetName="image1" Children="{DynamicResource Ani}" />
    </BeginStoryboard>
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard TargetName="image2" Children="{DynamicResource Ani}" />
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

Another approach would be to put the storyboard inside a style and apply the style to each image. This would be clearer and more reusable. You can get a rough idea how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206387/how-to-apply-storyboard-as-style)

Comment: XAML solution worked like charm. Is it possible to stop the rotation in code behind?

Comment: Evil follow-up question ;) Stopping is not as easy as it seems, as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623601/stop-wpf-animation-storyboard-begin-in-xaml-but-stopping-it-in-codebehind